# Flutter Build Failed: Execution failed for task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'

Tags: android, flutter

I recently upgrade my Flutter app from compileSdkVersion & targetSdkVersion 32 to 33 then to 34, along with upgrading AGP to 7.4, migrating the Flutter's Gradle plugins and updating all other dependencies in android\app\build.gradle to latest version. I tried to run the app but getting the following errors:

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'.
> Querying the mapped value of map(flatmap(provider(task 'processDebugGoogleServices', class com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask))) before task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' has completed is not supported

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

android\settings.gradle:

```
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.4.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.0-Beta4" apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.1" apply false
}

include ":app"
```

android\app\build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"

}

ext.kotlin_version = '2.0.0-Beta4' // Or your desired Kotlin version

def localProperties =  new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {

    compileSdkVersion 34

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.raaiq.appname"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
    implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'

}
```

android\build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

In android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
```

I have tried to downgrade `com.google.gms.google-services` to lower version such as 4.3.15 but it doesn't work. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

in the file `android\app\build.gradle` change this `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'` to this `implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.4')`

android\app\build.gradle:

```
 dependencies {
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.4')//<- go to this
}
```

android\build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Compare the files in the `android\app\build.gradle` file you have a line `ext.kotlin_version = '2.0.0-Beta4'` that should not be there, take a look at my android\build.gradle file and compare

Comment: use `firebase_core version: ^2.27.0` and follow these instructions [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?hl=es&platform=ios). Greetings, I hope I have helped you.

Comment: Thank you Yeferson Fernandez for your suggestion. I have tried it but I'm still getting the same error. After one day of trying out everything I could, I've managed to resolve the issue by downgrading the plugins. Will share it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the problem occurs whenever I use `"com.android.application" version "7.4.0"` so I've downgraded it to `7.3.0` and issue is resolved:

In `android\settings.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false 
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.0-Beta4" apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.1" apply false
}
```

I have also made the following changes:

1. `android\app\build.gradle`:  change `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7` to `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:2.0.0-Beta4'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
    implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
}
```

2. In `android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties`::

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.3-all.zip
```

This seems to be good for now as I can't upgrade to AGP8+ yet because for some weird reason the AGP Upgrade Assistant in my Android Studio Iguana is missing/not showing up.